# Add Existing Hybrid Connection to Azure App service Plan via ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-appservice, azure-app-service-plans, azure-hybrid-connections

We created an **Azure Standard Logic App** created via **ARM template**. This Logic App should use an existing **Hybrid Connection**.

I shared the ARM template below that we used to create **Azure App Service Plan**. I think I need to reference the Hybrid Connection settings in the template below, but couldn't find any document on how to do it.

How could I modify the template to set hybrid connection?

Thank you

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
    "dependsOn": [
    ],
    "kind": "",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
    "properties": {
        "maximumElasticWorkerCount": 20,
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
        "numberOfWorkers": "[parameters('numberOfWorkers')]",
        "workerSize": "[parameters('workerSize')]",
        "workerSizeId": "[parameters('workerSizeId')]",
        "zoneRedundant": false
    },
    "sku": {
        "Name": "[parameters('skuCode')]",
        "Tier": "[parameters('sku')]"
    },
    "tags": {
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the existed template, you can add a connection using [`Microsoft.Web/connections`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/connections?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) provider in ARM template as shown below.

I've created a sample office 365 connection and it worked as expected.

```bash
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "name": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "sku": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "skucode": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "workerSize": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "workerSizeId": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "numberOfWorkers": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "hostingPlanName": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "office365_1_Connection_DisplayName": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "office365_1_Connection_Name": {
      "type": "String"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "kind": "",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
      "properties": {
        "maximumElasticWorkerCount": 20,
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
        "numberOfWorkers": "[parameters('numberOfWorkers')]",
        "workerSize": "[parameters('workerSize')]",
        "workerSizeId": "[parameters('workerSizeId')]",
        "zoneRedundant": false
      },
      "sku": {
        "Name": "[parameters('skuCode')]",
        "Tier": "[parameters('sku')]"
      },
      "tags": {},
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('office365_1_Connection_Name')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('location'), '/managedApis/', 'office365')]"
        },
        "displayName": "[parameters('office365_1_Connection_DisplayName')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```bash
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "name": {
      "value": "plan1"
    },
    "location": {
      "value": ""
    },
    "sku": {
      "value": "Free"
    },
    "skucode": {
      "value": "F1"
    },
    "workerSize": {
      "value": "0"
    },
    "workerSizeId": {
      "value": "0"
    },
    "numberOfWorkers": {
      "value": "1"
    },
    "hostingPlanName": {
      "value": "newnsme"
    },
    "office365_1_Connection_Name": {
      "value": "connectionnew"
    },
    "office365_1_Connection_DisplayName": {
      "value": "newdis"
    }
  }
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you reply @Jahnavi. How do you relate `Microsoft.Web/serverfarms` and `Microsoft.Web/connections` resources?  I couldn't see the dependency or relation in the template?

Comment: @spt: I couldn't get the answer to my question in the comments. So it'd be better to keep this question open.

Comment: The above code was given as per your requirement. What is your exact blocker now? @serkanz

Comment: I couldn't understand the dependency between two resources `Microsoft.Web/serverfarms` and `Microsoft.Web/connections` depend on each other. There's no `dependson` field defined.

Comment: You can add `dependsOn` block in the above code. I've just created an Api connection and given the script. In order to link it with the web app, you need to add `dependsOn` as your ask. @serkanz

Comment: Is it understandable now? @serkanz